# How can I fix this C++ code — float type or double problem?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    const int N = 4;
    double a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0;

    for (i = 1 ; i <= N ; i++)
    {
        a += i;
        b += i * i;
    }

    c = a / N;
    d = b / N - c * c;

    printf("%.0f\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

Its result is 1, but I don't know exactly why the result is 1.  I think `c` is 3, and `N-c*c` is -2.25, so `d` is -13, so I think printing `d`'s result is -13 but the result is 1.

Where does this result comes from?

Comment: `I think c is 3` it isn't. And `d` isn't `1` either, its `1.25`, but you're not printing decimal digits.

Comment: a = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10; b = 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4 = 30; c = 10 / 4 = 2.5; d = 30 / 4 - 2.5*2.5 = 1.25. When printing c with 0 decimals, that is 1.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. Looks like C. And please indent your code properly.

Comment: yep. 
this code on purpose use %.0f;
i know c is 2.5 and N-c*c is 4 - 2.5*2.5. I understand this point but why
30 / 4 - 2.5*2.5 is 1.25 I don`t understand this point

Comment: Because your code is `d = b / N - c * c;`, not `d = N - c * c;`.

Comment: 30 / 4 - 2.5*.25 because that is what you wrote: `b / N - c * c`. `b` is 30, and the divison is done before subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not noticing the algorithm you are choosing for your solution.
the for loop iterates and make the variables like `a = 1+2+3+4` and `b = 1^2+2^2+3^3+4^4`
then `a = 10` and `b = 30` it makes `c=2.5` and `d=7.5-2.5^2=1.25` then you choose to print it
with `%.0f` and you get ONE.
If you want to print float with 2 point precision use `%.2f`.

Comment: I understand this problem In your effort 
Thank you so much all you guys. I hope you happy all day. thank you

Answer (score 1):

After the `for` loop, `a` is 10.0 and `b` is 30.0. Then `c` is being assigned `10.0 / 4` so `c` is `2.5`. The next line is equivalent to `d = (30.0 / 4) - (2.5 * 2.5)`, hence `d` is `7.5 - 6.25`, i.e. `1.25`. Then you trim all decimals by the `"%.0f"` argument you give to [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) so what remains is a `1`. As in, it's the **down rounded** version of your `1.25`.

If you change the the printing line to:

```
printf("%f\n", d);
```

Then you'll see all the decimal digits of your specific `d`.

As in, the `.0` after the `%` and before the `f` in the format string you gave `printf()` is what determines the number of decimal digits to print. Any digits beyond that are being rounded.

Comment: I understand this problem In your effort 
Thank you so much all you guys. I hope you happy all day. thank you

Comment: @HanbiMo Glad to help friend. Welcome to the site : )